# can't connect to mysql through GUI

Tags: mysql, user-interface, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have a DigitalOcean server I'm trying to connect to mysql through workbench but it gives me the error:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'forge' 
from your host to server at ip_address:3306:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip_address' (4)
```

When if i ssh into my server I'm able to log in in to MySQL through the command line no problem so I know my credentials are correct. What else could be causing the issue that I can't access my database through workbench or any other MySQL GUI?

Comment: Have you followed the `Configure Server Management` wizard ? (on Home -> (+) button).

Comment: yeah I have other mysql servers I'm connected it to that works this is the only server giving me an issue. @Niloct

Comment: @Niloct  also tried it with emma so its not a workbench error; however, if i just log in through the command line it works just fine

Comment: Clarify: can you log in locally to a remote host using `mysql` ? Or you have to ssh to the server first ?

Comment: @Niloct I ssh into my digitalOcean server and then I can log in to mysql through the command line

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-connect-mysql-workbench-to-my-vps

> MySQL Workbench works without any configuration necessary. When making a new connection, select "Standard TCP/IP over SSH", then change the SSH and MySQL parameters as necessary. (You should probably keep the SQL server IP address as 127.0.0.1.)

Comment: I have other digitalocean servers that workbench connects too no problem. This is the only server with the issue it literally makes no sense lol

Comment: Follow again the instructions in a new connection, to fill the `Standard TCP/IP over SSH` form: `Mysql Hostname` should be `127.0.0.1`, and SSH Hostname should be your SSH server IP and port (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:22).

Comment: Is your Mysql service listening on `127.0.0.1` at the host ?

Comment: @user3666882 So any news on the matter ? Have you solved the problem ?

Comment: Nope it times out the same way when i do a standard connection attempt

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I was using same username for SSH and MySQL with different passwords and just created a new user.

Long answer: I know this is old but it ranks number one for the problem I have and I found a solution that I hope will help other people.

I could not connect to MySQL over SSH using any of the GUI MySQL apps on my Mac.  I kept getting the same error as OP.

I finally solved the problem.  I was using the same username for SSH and MySQL and they had different passwords.  it worked fine in terminal but not in any of the GUIs.

The solution was to create a new MySQL user and it just worked.  I think what was happening is that it saw the same username and ignored the mysql password and tried to use the SSH password for MySQL.  The original MySQL user I was using had full admin privileges and my new user was set to read only. Not sure if that helps but I included this last info for reference.